# How to center an whole element based around a child element?

Tags: html, css, center

[Image showing the center line where the "vs" should be on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3oiL.png)

I will try to explain my problem as clear as I can. Here I am trying to make the "vs" in the center line and left and right elements flow beside it.

I tried using flex-box but it centers the whole thing as you can see in the photo above but not what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks!

Here is a snippet of what I have tried:

```html
<div class='flex page-container'>
      <div class='flex team-name'>
        THIS TEAM NAME IS LONG
        <img class='team-logo' src={TEAM_1_LOGO} />
      </div>
      <div class='vs'>VS</div>
      <div class='flex team-name'>
        <img class='team-logo' src={TEAM_2_LOGO} />
        SHORT NAME
      </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.page-container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1.5rem;
  max-height: 9rem;
  overflow: hidden;

  .team-name {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .team-logo {
    height: 6rem;
    max-width: 7rem;
    margin: 0 5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .vs {
    align-self: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post some snippets what you tried so far.

Comment: With flexbox you can justify every part of your content accordingly. Here is a great explanation of all of flexbox's properties. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. I would go on and wrap team 1, "vs" and team 2  in a parent element and add justify-content: space-between to that parent element.

Comment: I have added my code snippet in the post. @MdJunaidAlam

Comment: I tried flex-box on the parent. Can you give me a skeleton code example of your solution please? @J.Unkrass

Comment: I posted an answer. Please try if it works. You will probably have to remove some of the remaining positioning CSS code.

Comment: You should probably use a grid or flex column layout and for the left column use right-aligned text.

Comment: @TylerH check Zohir's answer. It basically does just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flex-basis:0` to ensure the elements truly share the available space, instead of calculating content of each flex item first, then distribute the left over space.

The rest is just simple alignment.

`flex: 1 0 0;` is short for

```
flex-grow:1;   // make element grow
flex-shrink:0; // prevent element from shrinking (preference really)
flex-basis:0;  // ignore content width
```

```css
/* Just for illustrating, To be removed */

body * {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

[center] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1.5rem;
}


/* ============ */

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 1.5rem;
  max-height: 9rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

.team-name {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.team-logo {
  max-height: 6rem;
  max-width: 7rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.vs {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.team-name~.team-name {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
True center example
<div center="">
  <div>VS</div>
</div>

<div class="flex page-container">
  <div class="flex team-name">
    THIS TEAM NAME IS LONG
    <img class="team-logo" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/163/200/300.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="vs">VS</div>
  <div class="flex team-name">
    <img class="team-logo" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/163/200/300.jpg"> SHORT NAME
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.page-container {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Or

```
.page-container {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

if you don't want the team names to be aligned to the edges

Comment: I will need to maintain a certain margin around "vs". 

Can I do that if I use those?

Comment: You can still change margin-left and margin-right. Maybe you'll have to give them negative values to adjust them accordingly. I hope there's a better solution to this, because it feels kind of hacky.

Comment: Yeah. I wouldn't able to use it dynamically if I hack my way into it.

Comment: I get it. Zohir's answer should be the way to go.